# How to get deleted answer back?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-answers

I am looking for an answer , I had provided [just for reference] , but I couldn't find it on SO.

How can I search such answers ?

Comment: You have... "rather a lot" of deleted answers on SO. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the question has been moved to another site (like superuser.com) you do not get informed about it. I know of no way to find out where that question went

**EDIT:** Try `user: me closed:1` in the search box. I'm not sure if it will work for finding answers; but if a question was migrated it will be closed, so this should pick it up (unless it was deleted after the migration...).

Comment: no, it cannot be the case, it could be  deleted by OP only

Comment: well, you are right

Comment: You can get to the question on the new site by following link in the "migrated to" message at the foot of the question.

Comment: @ChrisF it was not the case, the Question could be deleted only, Question was meant for SO only.

Comment: @org.life.java - that's a different case then and unless you've got 10K+ rep you won't be able to see your answer.

Comment: @ChrisF I remember it was upvoted atleast 5 time

Comment: @ChrisF: You can see your _own_ answers w/o 10k, right?

Comment: Yes you can, just tested it here. You just can't find (search for) them. But that doesn't change with 10k either.

Comment: @Henk You can see your own answers, but not questions. 10k users are able to see their own questions. However, moderators are able to see all of the deleted posts of a user. As Marc notes in the comments above, though, the author here has a lot of deleted posts so it would really help to narrow down which one it is.

Comment: @Henk - if the question has been deleted you won't be able to see it - even if you had the URL - unless you've got 10K+ rep.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search for deleted content.  If the question is not deleted, search for the question, and you should be able to view your answer.

If the question is also deleted then if you provide sufficient information about the answer then you might be able to convince a moderator to help you find the question and post the content of you answer here, though they are busy.

If you have a link to the question, other 10k users can do the same, but we can't search deleted content.